# SMTP permanent error: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

Can someone please solve this error:

```
create or replace procedure email
as
begin
utl_mail.send(sender => 'abc@gmail.com',
recipients => 'xyz@gmail.com',
subject    => 'Test utl_mail.send procedure',
message    => 'test!');
end;
/
```

Procedure created.

```
execute email;
BEGIN email; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 21
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 99
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 241
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 424
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_MAIL", line 594
ORA-06512: at "SYS.EMAIL", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I have configured database with utl_mail previously.

Comment: What SMTP server are you using?  Why do you believe that SMTP server is allowed to send email from a gmail account?

Comment: I am using this server mail.techaccesspak.com:25 from my office. Aint it allowed to send email from a gmail account?

Comment: Probably not, no.  Most likely, your mail server only allows messages to come from email accounts in the "techaccesspak.com" domain.

Comment: i have changed the sender, it still shows the same error.